# remove css for another page and keep it for the other

Tags: html, css

On my site, I have something like below as css for a table.

```
.table > thead > tr > th, 
.table > tbody > tr > th, 
.table > tfoot > tr > th, 
.table > thead > tr > td, 
.table > tbody > tr > td, 
.table > tfoot > tr > td  { 
    padding: 8px 15px;
}
```

So for another page of my same site, I want to remove this padding. Is there any way around to do this quickly?

Comment: You can use internal style sheet on other pages .table tr td, table tr th{padding:0;}

Answer (score 0):

I would first simplify the code.

And add a extra class to the second table

```css
td { border: 1px solid black; /* for demo */ }
.table th, 
.table td  { 
  padding: 8px 15px;
}
.table2 th,
.table2 td {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td>first table</td>
  </tr>
</table>


<table class="table table2">
  <tr>
    <td>first table</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use different class for the other table: .tableWhateverOtherName

Answer (score 0):

for the table you want to do this, set a class, and set padding for this class to padding = 0

```css
.nopadding{
  padding = 0;
  }
```

```html
<table class="nopadding">
  
</table>
```